# group by in dplyr and calculating percentages

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
   Service      Container_Pick_Day
    ABC              0
    ABC              1
    ABC              1
    ABC              2
    ABC              NA
    ABC              0
    ABC              1
    DEF              NA
    DEF              0
    DEF              1
    DEF              1
    DEF              1
    DEF              2
    DEF              1
```

Column `Container_Pick_Day` is numeric and consist of `NA` values.
What I want to do is calculate `Service` wise percentage of containers picked up on `0th day,after 1 day,2 day and so on` ignoring `NA` values

Desired dataframe would be

```
 Service      Container_Pick_Day      Percentage
    ABC              0                (2/6)*100 = 33.33 
    ABC              1                (3/6)*100 = 50  
    ABC              2                (1/6)*100 = 16.67
    DEF              0                (1/6)*100 = 16.67
    DEF              1                (3/6)*100 = 50
    DEF              2                (1/6)*100 = 16.67
```

I did following in R,but its generating NA values in output

```
  df%>% 
     group_by(Service) %>%
     summarise(pick_day_perc = n()/sum(Container_Pick_Day),na.rm=T) %>% 
     as.data.frame()
```

Do I have to group by `Service and Container_Pick_Day` both ?

Comment: Looks like all you need is `sum(Container_Pick_Day, na.rm=TRUE)` ?

Comment: I want service wise containers picked up percentage day wise.. Percentage of containers picked on same day,1st day,2nd day.

Comment: Yes I understand, but you say that "but its generating NA values in output", so I meant to replace the sum() bit with the bit I in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, I did that but total sum of percentage is going beyond 100

Comment: Maybe something like: `df %>% filter(!is.na(Container_Pick_Day)) %>% group_by(Service,Container_Pick_Day) %>% summarise(Percentage=n()) %>% group_by(Service) %>% mutate(Percentage=Percentage/sum(Percentage)*100)`. Guess there are less verbose solutions

Comment: This works perfectly. What I was doing wrong?

Comment: Or you can use `count` i.e. `df %>% filter(complete.cases(Container_Pick_Day)) %>% count(Service, Container_Pick_Day) %>% group_by(Service) %>% transmute(Container_Pick_Day, Percentage=n/sum(n)*100)`

Comment: A slightly different variant of the one provided by @nicola could be `df %>% na.omit() %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(ptg = n()) %>% group_by(Service) %>% mutate(ptg = prop.table(ptg)*100)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adding an answer based on all comments above provided by @nicola, @akrun and myself,

```
library(dplyr)

#nicola
df %>% 
 filter(!is.na(Container_Pick_Day)) %>% 
 group_by(Service,Container_Pick_Day) %>% 
 summarise(Percentage=n()) %>% 
 group_by(Service) %>% 
 mutate(Percentage=Percentage/sum(Percentage)*100)

#akrun
df %>% 
 filter(complete.cases(Container_Pick_Day)) %>% 
 count(Service, Container_Pick_Day) %>% 
 group_by(Service) %>% 
 transmute(Container_Pick_Day, Percentage=n/sum(n)*100)

#Sotos
df %>% 
 na.omit() %>% 
 group_by_all() %>% 
 summarise(ptg = n()) %>% 
 group_by(Service) %>% 
 mutate(ptg = prop.table(ptg)*100)
```

All resulting to,

> ```
> Service Container_Pick_Day Percentage
>    <fctr>              <int>      <dbl>
> 1     ABC                  0   33.33333
> 2     ABC                  1   50.00000
> 3     ABC                  2   16.66667
> 4     DEF                  0   16.66667
> 5     DEF                  1   66.66667
> 6     DEF                  2   16.66667
> ```