# What is the simplest R function for make a frequency tab with 2 factors?

Tags: r, statistics, bigdata

I am working in the following data.frame with aprox 40.000.000 rows:

```
structure(list(glucose = c(25.355843637, 10.886229826, 28.122760385, 
20.865273834, 34.563779699, 26.489825911, 43.454200724, 43.544919306, 
28.984586913, 29.937132023), nefa = c(21763.764082, 246228.88267, 
75785.828326, 13397.168282, 23325.824788, 20306.309909, 696440.45064, 
14358.729437, 87055.05633, 13397.168282), gluc_cat = c(1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L), cont = c(551838.59904, 2680504.2066, 
2131306.6906, 279535.5848, 806228.66928, 537910.61438, 30263263.134, 
625249.71469, 2523254.8464, 401072.79558), season = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Fall", "Spring", 
"Summer", "Winter"), class = "factor"), md = c(120438.488265459, 
115074.616033211, 62272.4097576723, 52303.3447941409, 74214.9213922757, 
44565.2765555817, 11821.9466392891, 58251.7622084503, 153983.271493517, 
41509.1943282798), st = c(33457899969.5155, 23427439594.7117, 
8572667146.93446, 6076535084.06137, 8356580101.09359, 7100437423.93883, 
3942148413.49136, 5200020083.88787, 20620429883.9183, 6554207754.48383
), bt = c(277800.730077007, 203584.77310018, 137663.969971521, 
116178.70918156, 112599.729870001, 159326.677016874, 333460.176549098, 
89268.0304722786, 133913.441920777, 157897.734719908), ol = c("prim", 
"mult", "prim", "prim", "mult", "prim", "mult", "mult", "prim", 
"mult")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

trying to make a frequency tab of the variable glucose by "gluc_cat" (a factor of glucose) and "season" (a factor of the date) like this:

```
gluc_cat   Fall Spring  Summer  Winter
   1       60%    60%     59%     60%
   2       9%     9%      9%      9%
   3       7%     7%      7%      7%
   4       3%     3%      3%      3%
   5       6%     6%      6%      6%
   6       10%    10%     11%     10%
   NA       5%    5%      5%      5%
```

I now that there is some questions that looks alike this. But I could not get this format of table with any of their's codes, with one variable "inside" the table.

I tried this codes:

```
df$gluc_cat <- factor(df$gluc_cat)
df$gseason <- factor(df$season)

freq <- df %>%
  group_by (season, gluc_cat, glucose) %>%
  summarise (n=n()) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * n/sum(n), 0), "%"))
freq
#-------------------------
freq <- table(df$season,cdf$sgluc_cat, df7$glucose)
freq
#--------------------------
mytable <- xtabs(~ season+gluc_cat+glucose, data=df)
mytable
#--------------------------------
mytable <- c(df$season,df$gluc_cat,df$glucose)
#--------------------------------
mytable <- sapply(teste, table)
```

But none of them gave me what I need.

Thanks in advance and sorry if it is too basic.

Comment: Assuming you have shared only subset of your data since you don't have `gluc_cat` with 2, 3 etc. Do you need `table(df$gluc_cat, df$season)` ?

Comment: `prop.table(xtabs(glucose~gluc_cat+season,df),2)`

Comment: `round(prop.table(table(df$gluc_cat, df$season),2)*100)`?

Comment: Ronak, in this code I think I will not get the results of glucose, but of glucose cat. And I do not know if I could explain well. I need the frequency of glucose in the 2 conditions. For ex: in the class gluc_cat 1 and in the summer; in the class 2 and in the summer; in the class 5 and in the winter ...      And yes, this is a subset only to example, because my data.frame has aprox 40.000.000 rows.

Comment: Onyambu, thank you very much! I guess the code prop.table(xtabs(glucose~gluc_cat+season,df),2) worked. I think his code round(prop.table(table(df$gluc_cat, df$season),2)*100) will not consider the variable glucose, right?

Comment: Onyambu, could you please explain me why you wrote the 2 after the parenthesis in the first code?

Comment: And what is the best way to plot it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(season, gluc_cat) %>%
  summarise(n_tmp=n()) %>%
  group_by(season) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq=paste0(round(100 * n_tmp/sum(n_tmp), 0), "%")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-n_tmp) %>%
  spread(key=season, value=rel.freq, fill="0%")
```

which, for the input provided, gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  gluc_cat Fall  Spring Summer Winter
     <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1        1 100%  100%   86%    0%    
2        4 0%    0%     0%     100%  
3        6 0%    0%     14%    0%
```

This is very similar to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45344391/570918), but adds the `spread` to achieve the wide format requested.

Comment: Thank you merv, but I think with this code I do not get the results of the variable glucose "inside" the table, right? Only of the glucose_cat. I do not know if I could explain well. I need the frequency of glucose in the 2 conditions. For ex: in the class gluc_cat 1 and in the summer; in the class 2 and in the summer; in the class 5 and in the winter ...

Comment: @AnaPaulaFranzoni Yeah, I don't follow. In your example, the columns sum to 100%, which is what this does. It would help if you showed the expected output from the input you provided, and not examples from different subsets of the data.